# If condition for 2 timestamps with date difference in php

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a table that shall store expired timestamps. I would like to store them for an interval of something between 1 day before a given timestamp until 3 days after that.

I tried this:

```
$timeStamp = 1682936936; //2023-5-1 13:58 for example
$nowTime = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

$oneDayBefore = strtotime("-1 day",$timeStamp);
$threeDaysAfter = strtotime("+3 days",$timeStamp);

if($nowTime > $oneDayBefore && $nowTime < $threeDaysAfter){
    echo "yes";
}
else{
    echo "no";
}
```

But that does not return correct results.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Specific problem with your code as-written:

`strtotime()` takes a date string, but you're giving it a timestamp. You need to feed it `$nowTime` instead, eg:

```php
$oneDayBefore = strtotime("-1 day",$nowTime);
$threeDaysAfter = strtotime("+3 days",$nowTime);
```

Also, if you use the DateTime functions instead you don't have to convert back and forth between strings and rely on functions just magically knowing what your date format is:

```php
$timeStamp = 1682936936;

$now   = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($timeStamp);
$begin = (clone $now)->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$end   = (clone $now)->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));

if( $now > $begin && $now < $end){
    echo "yes";
}
else{
    echo "no";
}
echo PHP_EOL;

var_dump(
    $now->format('U'),
    $now->format('c'),
    $begin->format('U'),
    $begin->format('c'),
    $end->format('U'),
    $end->format('c')
);
```

Output:

```
yes
string(10) "1682936936"
string(25) "2023-05-01T12:28:56+02:00"
string(10) "1682850536"
string(25) "2023-04-30T12:28:56+02:00"
string(10) "1683196136"
string(25) "2023-05-04T12:28:56+02:00"
```

DateTime object allow *far* more control than the old utility functions like `strtotime()`, especially if you need to do anything with timezones.

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

this worked good:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/tehran');
$timeStamp = 1682936936; //2023-5-1 13:58 for example
$nowTime = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i")); // edit: delete secend

$oneDayBefore = strtotime("-1 day",$timeStamp);
$threeDaysAfter = strtotime("+3 days",$timeStamp);

if($nowTime >= $oneDayBefore && $nowTime <= $threeDaysAfter){
    echo "yes";
}
else{
    echo "no";
}
```

i add default timezone and remove second from now time and add = to < or >
now work and results is true for every timestamp